# Failed to update metadata after 48 ms

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

```
val props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "foo:9092,bar:9092")
props.put("acks", "all")
props.put("retries", 1)
props.put("batch.size", 10000)
props.put("linger.ms", 5)
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

try {
   producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, msg.toJson)).get()
   true
} catch {
   case ex: Throwable => {
      println(ex)
      false
   }
}
```

This code throws an exception

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 48 ms.\n\tat 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:686)\n\tat 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:449)\n\tat 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:339)\
```

Note that I am posting data against production cluster so its up and running and many applications are already successfully publishing messages to the topic. Its just my code which is failing to publish.

Comment: I noticed that the max.block.ms was set to 48 ms which is an extremely low value. Why do you set such a value to retrieve metadata?

Comment: @amethystic That's not in the configs given, where did you get that from?

Comment: From "Failed to update metadata after 48ms".

Comment: @amethystic I've also been getting errors of less than 100ms even though my max.block.ms setting is set to 120000, and it waits 120s before throwing the exception.

Comment: It turned out the client failed to retrieve metadata from brokers, so ensure the connectivity to foo:9092 and bar:9092

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is something wrong with hostname or port since you are not able to connect your producer with TimeoutException. Have you tried running kafka-console-producer.sh using the same producer config? Did it really work on that machine? Perhaps, the connection to broker is protected with SSL or SASL. Don't forget to turn on TRACE logging in config/tools-log4j.properties, this will help you to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same timeout exception earlier, and when I tried to send a message using the console producer I got `WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 656 : {metadata-1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)` back.

For myself, stopping and restarting the broker got everything working again.